# Ajax call with different JSON responses

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have Ajax script that calls a PHP file, making a query to MySQL and then formats the response in JSON so I can use it. My problem is that with 1 id, which I send with the Ajax call, I need to make several queries to different tables, some of them returning 1 result, and some multiple results. All of that data has to be fetched with the same Ajax call, so my question is how to properly format the JSON so I can use it with the javascript. Here's my PHP:

```
try
{   
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM newLoads WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1 ";   
    $s= $conn->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error SQL SELECT";
    exit();
}
while ($row = $s->fetch())
{ 
    $load['id'] = $row['id'];
    $load['dateAdded'] = $row['dateAdded'];
    ...
    $all['load'] = $load;   
}
print json_encode($all);
```

Which returns as `{"load":{"id":"00000361","dateAdded":"2015-01-15"...}}`
and it's fine, but how do I proceed with the next query which has to contain multiple responses? I tried adding second query to `$all`, but it only works when it's a single result, while it may be multiple. I suppose it's just a syntax issue, but I'm new to Ajax so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your response should be one array. If there's only one result, it will be one array of one element.

Comment: You need to build all the data you need in the response into a single data structure (array, object, array of objects, etc.) and then serialize to JSON only at the point where you are going to return the response.  How to structure it to work with javascript is really up to you and the needs of your application. I would start by thinking about how to structure the data for best use in javascript and building your server-side data structure to match that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do (`$s2` being the result of your second query):

```
$all['items'] = array();

while ($row = $s2->fetch()) {
    $all['items'][] = $row;
}
```

In Javascript you then need to loop through the items, for example:

```
for (i = 0; i < j.items.length; i++) { 
   console.log(j.items[i]);
}
```

Comment: Actually i think that would work. I'm just not sure how to use the response. For the first query i use `j.load.id`, for example, to print the result. How do i print all the results for the second query? `j.items.id` returns `undefined`

Comment: Updated the answer some more. The id would then be j.items[i].id for each item inside the loop.

Comment: Glad to be of help, happy coding!